# Url.Action for [FromRoute] parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

In ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0, I have a controller action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details([FromRoute] string bigId, string smallId)
```

How can I get the link for it a View?

Using `Url.Action()` like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "MyController",
            new {  bigId = Model.BigId, smallId = Model.SmallId })">
  Details
</a>
```

generates the `href="/Mycontroller/Details?bigId=123&smallId=456"`, but i need it like `"/Mycontroller/Details/123?smallId=456"`

Comment: Try `($"Details", "MyController",  {Model.BigId}, new { smallId = Model.SmallId })`

Comment: Nope, "No overload for method 'Action' takes 4 arguments". See my answer below, the method needs to be decorated with HttpGet("...")

Comment: Fair enough, I believe also if you actually name the method `GetDetails` you might be able to skip the decoration as the Web Api tech would work out that it's a `GET` from convention (haven't tested though but read somewhere about it)

Comment: @VishalChhodwani please stop adding random **bold formatting** to posts, as that definitely doesn't improve the question quality.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am not doing random bold formatting, I just **Highlight Keywords** that are important to notice for better solution.

Comment: @VishalChhodwani yeah please stop doing that. It doesn't increase readability, it actually decreases it. See for example [A user seems to be making a lot of unnecessary formatting edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265580/a-user-seems-to-be-making-a-lot-of-unnecessary-formatting-edits) and other related discussions on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found the answer.

The method in the controller needs to be decorated with

```
[HttpGet("Details/{bigId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details([FromRoute] string bigId, string smallId)
```

Then Url.Action in the view generates the proper href: `"/Mycontroller/Details/123?smallId=456"`